# How to handle if SelectedItem is "cancelled" by object

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox where SelectedItem is binded to a property in a business object.  Typically it works just fine. However, there is logic in the object's property setter than will occasionally "cancel" a new value that it deems invalid.  This is done in a silent manner, ie no exception thrown just the property value does not change.  In such situations, I'd like the combobox's SelectedItem to revert back to the previous selection, since technically the new selection never was propagated to the underlying property.  Currently the combobox just stays put on the new selection, which is misleading since that is not the true value of the underlying property.

How can I make sure the combobox displays the true value of the property always?

Comment: How are you binding the SelectedItem property of the ComboBox?

Comment: SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ProjectionType}" .... where ProjectionType is the name of the property of the binded object.  It is an enum property.

Comment: The business object needs to cancel and then call NotifyPropertyChanged so the old value is propagated back to the UI.

Comment: Did you try pushing the old values into a stack and popping them into ProjectionType?  With a subsequent call to OPC?

Comment: While the combobox is trying to set the underlying property, any attempt to revert back or raise PropChanged event appears to be ignored by combobox.  See my answer for a link about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I came across this:

http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2011/04/28/the-case-of-the-confused-combobox-a-wpfmvvm-bedtime-story/

The solution given of subclassing the combobox and forcing it to update the target upon selection changed works on my machine, but the commentators on that site suggest that even this isn't bulletproof.  Several websites mention that the wpf combobox is quirky in this regard. Apparently MS made the dubious decision to have the combobox ignore any further notifications while setting the binded property, which makes sense until you come across a situation like this.  That at least is the opinion of other WPF experts, which I definitely am not :)

Answer (score 0):

need to call NotifyPropertyChanged

```
private enum1 e1 = enum1.val1;

public enum1 E1
{
    get { return e1 } 
    set 
    {
        if (e1 == value) return;
        if (OK(value)) e1 = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(E1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of this but it didn't work on my machine.  After some web searching I've learned the wpf combobox has some issues with this, see my answer post for a link.  Apparently its behavior can even be different between wpf 3.5 and 4.0!